In Angular, how to declare a variable to be of type MatSlideToggle
I'm working with an Angular project. In a certain component I have this in my html file (code snippet):
<mat-slide-toggle #powerswitch 

in the component's ts file I can refer to this element like so and programmatically set it, all works fine (code snippet):
@ViewChild("powerswitch") PowerSwitch: any;

this.PowerSwitch._checked = true

at the moment PowerSwitch is defined as being of type any. How can I define it as being of type MatSlideToggle?
Just doing this is not enough (as compiler cannot find name MatSlideToggle):
@ViewChild("powerswitch") PowerSwitch: MatSlideToggle;

Would make the code nicer to debug as one could see the type of the variable at coding time.
Thanks.

Since you are referring to an internal private property, the compiler throws an error. If you want to set it programmatically, please use the checked input property."
 @ViewChild("powerswitch") PowerSwitch: MatSlideToggle;
 this.PowerSwitch.checked = true


Could you try like below, we can use the read property to specify which export we need from the ViewChild
@ViewChild("powerswitch", { read: MatSlideToggle }) PowerSwitch: MatSlideToggle;

read

Used to read a different token from the queried elements.

The following values are supported by read:

Any class with the @Component or @Directive decorator
Any provider defined on the injector of the component that is matched by the selector of this query
Any provider defined through a string token (e.g. {provide: 'token', useValue: 'val'})
A TemplateRef, ElementRef, and ViewContainerRef


Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The two references to MatSlideToggle in that line are underscored in VSCode and each says "Cannot find name 'MatSlideToggle'". Should I be importing anything at the top of the ts file for this to work?

@gnitsuk import it import { MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
